# Connect to hardware device attached with USB cross platform

Tags: java, connection, usb, hardware

I have hardware a plotter machine. This device doesn't have any kind of driver. When I attached USB cable of this hardware to my machine(windows) it comes under "unspecified device" in control panel -> printers and devices. I want to build an application which can connect to this hardware (plotter without driver) connected via USB. I have checked with usb4java but it din't work. Can you guys please help me. ?

My application must be able to run in any platform, so in any machine I can just attached usb cable and my application must be able to detect the hardware and able to get connection.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Perhaps you should have a look at [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also try asking the manufacturer for the device's Windows drivers.

If the device doesn't have any Windows drivers, without knowing anything about your device, I would suggest that you use [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) to attach WinUSB (Microsoft's generic USB device driver) to your printer.  Then you can use [libusb](http://libusb.info/) to write a cross-platform application that detects the machine and talks to it.

However, it might be that your device actually belongs to particular *USB device class*, such as the CDC ACM class.  In that case, it would be better to install the drivers for that particular class.  You can get your driver's descriptors using the Linux `lsusb` utility and examine them to see what class your device is.

Comment: Thanks David. I've asked manufacturer but they've not build any driver for Mac that's why I am stuck here. I will look into this "Zadig".